# Functional component state persistency

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React functional component and I am using Socket.io.
Every time Socket fails to connect the server (self-try every 4 seconds) it calls function `ioConnectError`.

**Expected behavior:**
If `state` is not `lost` call `setState('lost')`. If the current `state` is already `lost` - do nothing.

**Current behavior:** In function `ioConnectError` state is being all the time `ok` (it's the default value) even if it has been set to `lost`. It causes a double re-render of the component.

```js
const ConnectionStatus=(props)=> {
    let [state, setState] = useState('ok');

    const ioConnectError=()=> {
        console.log(state); //this is always default value ('ok') - why?
        state !== 'lost' && setState('lost');
    }

    const ioReconnect=()=> {
        state !== 'reconnected' && setState('reconnected');
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect'); // this is being called only once, on mount
        props.io.on('connect_error',ioConnectError); // being called every 4 seconds
        props.io.on('reconnect',ioReconnect);
        return () => {
            props.io.removeListener("connect_error",ioConnectError);
            props.io.removeListener("reconnect",ioReconnect);    
        }
    }, [])

    return state;
}
```

Comment: I added a solution, you may not be notified because I deleted it first so check it out

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the evaluation of `state !== 'lost'` inside `ioConnectError` lexical scope, the `state` will always refer to the initial value.

Try moving `ioConnectError` to `useEffect` scope (because it's redundant in the component scope and will assign a new unused function on every render) and using the functional `useState` instead (to always refer the current state).

Also, notice that this is a custom hook and not a `Component`, better called it with "use" prefix:

```
const useConnectionStatus = ({ io }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState('ok');

  useEffect(() => {
    const ioConnectError = () => {
      setState(state => {
        if (state !== 'lost') {
          return 'lost';
        }
        return state;
      });
    };

    io.on('connect_error', ioConnectError);
    return () => {
      io.removeListener('connect_error', ioConnectError);
    };
  }, []);

  return state;
};
```

Reference - [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Comment: `state !== 'lost' ? 'lost' : 'ok'` this will make the state changes periodically between `lost` and `ok` (lost -> ok -> lost ..)

Comment: Is there any due to use `if` statement in `setState` instead of `state !== 'lost' && setState('lost');`? Like I don't want to `setState(state=>state)`... As I've tested - the value of `state` is still `ok` in this case and keeps re-rendering itself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in closure. Since you're using `useEffect()` with empty list of dependencies, you always use initial effect-function which holds initial value of state in its closure.

If you need it to be updated - you have two options:

- add `state` as dependency

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (state !== 'lost') {
    // your effect will be called twice, so you can skip subscription when connection lost
  }
}, [ lost ]);
```

- use ref instead of state

```js
const state = useRef('ok');

useEffect(() => {
  // use state.current here instead
}, []);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how do you mean your first example. I'm using effect only in due of removeListener on unmount. useEffect is being called only once (which is right) and I don't want to call it again (not even on state change).

Comment: The first solution will make unnecessary calls to the socket for adding and removing listeners. The second solution won't work because there is nothing to trigger a render and the returned `state` from the function won't be updated.

Comment: 1st solution won't cause unnecessary calls, if this calls will be under condition (`if (state !== 'lost')`). I'm not sure we need to re-render. I thought the problem is in using actual value of state in `useEffect()`. If we need to update our component as well, it's probably better to use `setState()` with a callback

Answer (score 0):

As I've tested so far it seems to be enough to put `state` (instead of `[]`) as a second parameter of `useEffect` which tells React that my effect depends only on value of `state`.

As [Andres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11898502/andres) mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58709393/functional-component-state-persistency#answer-58709615)

> add `state` as dependency

So I've tried:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect'); // this is being called only once, on mount
    props.io.on('connect_error',ioConnectError); // being called every 4 seconds
    props.io.on('reconnect',ioReconnect);
    return () => {
        props.io.removeListener("connect_error",ioConnectError);
        props.io.removeListener("reconnect",ioReconnect);    
    }
}, [state]) // added state as 2nd param
```

---

**pros**

- my component stopped re-rendering with every `ioConnectError` call
- `state` doesn't use default value but keeps value `lost` until it being changed (which is exactly what I've wanted)

**cons**

- listeners `props.io.on(...);` are being removed and attached again with every `state` change

Comment: Will this effect be called on 'unmount' too?

Comment: You can attach/remove listeners conditionally: `if (state !== 'lost') { props.io.on(...); return () => { ... } }`

Comment: It will work but it overcomplicated things and the code isn't robust with all those conditions

Comment: @Andres Ty for your time. I want to attach/remove them ONLY on MOUNT and UNMOUNT of component. (it doesn't depend on state)